# Issue in creating Tree in JS

Tags: javascript, treeview, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

*(Disclaimer, I am not an expert in JS. Currently learning and doing. Excuse me if I made any blunders. but help me)*

I have been trying to implement a new functionality to the existing Autodesk Forge Hubs code. I want to retrieve `derivatives.data.id` from the `relationships` object of a response body. The response body is from the API

```
`GET /api/hubs/${hubId}/projects/${projectId}/contents/${itemId}/versions`
```

To explain my issue I will put the code snippet as `before` and `after`

**Before:**

```
function createTreeNode(id, text, icon, children = false) {
    return { id, text, children, itree: { icon } };
}


async function getVersions(hubId, projectId, itemId) {
    const versions = await getJSON(`/api/hubs/${hubId}/projects/${projectId}/contents/${itemId}/versions`);
    return versions.map(version => createTreeNode(`version|${version.id}`, version.attributes.createTime, 'icon-version'));
}
```

Output : [image: Tree formation with versions] Working fine

**After (Modified code) :**

```
function createTreeNode(id, text, icon, children = false, derivativesId = null) {
    return { id, text, children, itree: { icon, derivativesId } };
}

async function getVersions(hubId, projectId, itemId) {
    const versions = await getJSON(`/api/hubs/${hubId}/projects/${projectId}/contents/${itemId}/versions`);
    versions.forEach(version => {
        const { id, attributes,relationships } = version;
        const derivativesId = relationships?.derivatives?.data?.id || null;
        console.log(`Version ID: ${id}`, `Derivatives ID: ${derivativesId}`);
    });

    return versions.map(version => {
        const { id, attributes,relationships} = version;
        const derivativesId = relationships?.derivatives?.data?.id || null; // Extract 'id' from 'derivatives' object

        return createTreeNode(`version|${id}`, attributes.createTime, 'icon-version', derivativesId);
    });
}
```

Output:[image: Not loading a tree] Not working

Here is the original code by autodesk: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-hubs-browser-nodejs/develop/wwwroot/sidebar.js

What mistake did I make, and why is it not loading the tree?

I know there are two versions (response body) that have no `derivatives` inside the `relationships`. Is this causing the tree to continue looping or what is the error? How to handle the situation?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of problem. The placement of `derivativesId`  within the `createTreeNode` stops the tree load when there is a null.

```
function createTreeNode(id, text, icon, children = false, derivativesId = null) {
    return { id, text, children, itree: { icon, derivativesId } };
}
```

Answer:

```
function createTreeNode(id, text, icon, children = false, derivativesId = null) {
    return { id, text, children, itree: { icon}, derivativesId } };
}
```